# How to claim unallocated space on disk

Tags: windows-server-2008, hard-drive, diskmanagement, partition

On windows 2008 R1 server, I have a 1Tb disk that has about 400Gb at the end that's not used. I have the boot partition, then a logic volume, then the free space.  I want to create a new simple volume (basic, I'm assuming) at the end, but it keeps crapping out. For some reason it reports there is not enough space to complete the operation.

I've tried creating a 200gb basic disk, well inside the boundary of supposed free space, but it still craps out.

If it can't be done by Server Manager, what would you recommend, per third party tools, that would get the job done.

Any help appreciated.
 Bob.

Answer (score 3):

I would echo what @Chopper3 says-- what you've got *should* work.

- Fire up `diskpart`. At the `DISKPART>` prompt enter `list disk` and look down the list of disks for the one you want to create the partition on. (If you have multiple disks this can be a challenge. The ordinal number on the disk is the same as shown in 'Computer Management' and is probably 0 in the case of your question. Better safe than sorry, though.)
- Enter `select disk #` substituting the ordinal of the disk that you want to parition for #.
- You can do a `list partition` to see the partitions already on the disk.
- Enter `create partition primary` to create another primary partition.
- Enter `list partition` again to see the results of your changes.
- Assuming a partition gets created you can enter `select partition #` (substituting in the ordinal for the partition you created for #) and `assign letter=x:` (substituting in whatever drive letter you'd like assigned to the partition for x).
- You can format the partition in `diskpart` using the `format` command (`format fs=ntfs quick`) or your favorite format command.

If this acts up post the output of `list disk` and `list partition` as an edit on your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `DISKPART` command or the [Partd Magic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php) utility, but to be honest I don't know what's going on, you should be fine to use the regular disk management plugin like you've tried.